# WINAPI - Set background & text color of a combo box dropdown

Tags: winapi, colors, combobox, common-controls

So I was trying to set a ComboBox's background & text color using Common-Controls & WINAPI.
I did manage to set the background & text color of the combo box itself, but the colors of its dropdown list remain the same.

Here is pretty much what I did:
When creating the combo box, I used the `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` style (along with `WS_VISIBLE` & `WS_CHILD`).
Then in the window handler function, I handled the `CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX` messge in the following way:

```
SetBkMode(dc, OPAQUE);
SetTextColor(dc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
SetBkColor(dc, 0x383838);
comboBrush = CreateSolidBrush(0x383838); //global var
return (LRESULT)comboBrush;
```

As I said, this only colors the combobox itself, and not its drop-down list.
How can I can color the drop down list as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the background color and text color of the combo box, you can handle the [WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorlistbox) and [WM_CTLCOLOREDIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit) messages respectively.

> WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX : Sent to the parent window of a list box before
> the system draws the list box. By responding to this message, the
> parent window can **set the text and background colors of the list box**
> by using the specified display device context handle.

Some code:

```
   // Create Combox control
   int xpos = 100;            // Horizontal position of the window.
   int ypos = 100;            // Vertical position of the window.
   int nwidth = 200;          // Width of the window
   int nheight = 200;         // Height of the window
   HWND hwndParent = hWnd; // Handle to the parent window

   hWndComboBox = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOX, TEXT(""),
       CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_CHILD |  WS_VISIBLE, 
       xpos, ypos, nwidth, nheight, hwndParent, NULL, hInstance,
       NULL);

   // load the combobox with item list.  
   // Send a CB_ADDSTRING message to load each item

   TCHAR Planets[9][10] =
   {
       TEXT("Mercury"), TEXT("Venus"), TEXT("Terra"), TEXT("Mars"),
       TEXT("Jupiter"), TEXT("Saturn"), TEXT("Uranus"), TEXT("Neptune"),
       TEXT("Pluto??")
   };

   TCHAR A[16];
   int  k = 0;

   memset(&A, 0, sizeof(A));
   for (k = 0; k <= 8; k += 1)
   {
       wcscpy_s(A, sizeof(A) / sizeof(TCHAR), (TCHAR*)Planets[k]);

       // Add string to combobox.
       SendMessage(hWndComboBox, (UINT)CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)A);
   }

   // Send the CB_SETCURSEL message to display an initial item 
   //  in the selection field  
   SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM)2, (LPARAM)0);

   ...
```

**Updated:**

```
//Windows Process
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {    
    case WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX:
    {       
        COMBOBOXINFO info;
        info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
        SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO, 0, (LPARAM)&info);
        COMBOBOXINFO info1;
        info1.cbSize = sizeof(info1);
        SendMessage(hWndComboBox1, CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO, 0, (LPARAM)&info1);

        if ((HWND)lParam == info.hwndList)
        {
            HDC dc = (HDC)wParam;
            SetBkMode(dc, OPAQUE);
            SetTextColor(dc, RGB(255, 255, 0));
            SetBkColor(dc, 0x383838); //0x383838
            HBRUSH comboBrush = CreateSolidBrush(0x383838); //global var
            return (LRESULT)comboBrush;
        } 
        if ((HWND)lParam == info1.hwndList)
        {
            HDC dc = (HDC)wParam;
            SetBkMode(dc, OPAQUE);
            SetTextColor(dc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
            SetBkColor(dc, RGB(0, 0, 255)); 
            HBRUSH comboBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255)); 
            return (LRESULT)comboBrush;
        }
    }
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
    {
        HWND hWnd = (HWND)lParam;
        HDC dc = (HDC)wParam;
        if (hWnd == hWndComboBox)
        {
            SetBkMode(dc, OPAQUE);
            SetTextColor(dc, RGB(255, 0, 255));
            SetBkColor(dc, 0x383838); //0x383838
            HBRUSH comboBrush = CreateSolidBrush(0x383838); //global var
            return (LRESULT)comboBrush;
        }
        else if (hWnd == hWndComboBox1)
        {
            SetBkMode(dc, OPAQUE);
            SetTextColor(dc, RGB(255, 255, 0));
            SetBkColor(dc, RGB(0, 255, 0)); 
            HBRUSH comboBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0)); 
            return (LRESULT)comboBrush;
        }
    }
    ...
```

Change the background color by comparing the edit handle and listbox handle returned by the window.

Debug:

[image]

Comment: The given handle (lParam) in the `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` message seems to not be the combobox's handle. Is there any other way to identify the combo box inside of the window handler? what if I want to have two combo boxes for example, each one with a different color?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: For selected item background color, need owner-drawn ComboBox.